# Non-login based unique user request identification

Tags: angularjs, flask, uniqueidentifier

I have a `Flask` / `Angular` site that I would like to display a short tutorial walkthrough upon the user's first request of the home page.

I don't want the user to see this demo again so I'm thinking of ways to handle a unique user request without login.

I have found this solution but even its created notes some of its problems [Evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie)

Does anyone have experience with Evercookie in use where it doesn't affect user experience? Which storage method did you use? Are there better alternatives to Evercookie?

Comment: Considered just using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this?

Comment: @Gennon Have you used localStorage previously? What's your experience with is?  Does it survive clearing cookies in Chrome?

Comment: Just thought it would fit the spec. The values will be connected to the browser, so the user will get the demo again if changing computer or browser. The user can delete the data the same way they delete cookies.